# Merging multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am currently using the following method to merge multiple `UIView`'s:

```
targetImageView.addSubview(view1)
targetImageView.addSubview(view2)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetImageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
targetImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This method works well if all the views are static. However, if one of the views have animated content, say a video, animation, or gif ... then this method would not work because I think it just takes a snapshot of all the views inside the frame of the `targetImageView`.

What is another way to combine multiple views even if one of the views has non-static content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cgrect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: desireWidthOfUIView, height: desireHeightOfUIView);

    let view1 = UIView(frame: cgrect)
    let view2 = UIView(frame: cgrect)
```

I Hope this help. :)